# Override configuration java.security inside java application

Tags: java, keystore, jceks

Recently switched my java runtime version and found that one of the keys in our external jceks keystore is being rejected when my program tries to extract it from the keystore and encrypt a message. The key was provided to us a long time ago it was generated by an IBM JDK.

I have tried in my local environment by adding it in the jceks.key.serialFilter of the java.security file and it works.

But before I bother the DevOps team to add it in images on the testing/production environment, I was wondering if there is anyway I can set it in my program to override it during the program startup.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to achieve this with

```
System.setProperty("jceks.key.serialFilter", "enter your own value")
```